# How to create a view's controller that nested to another view file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a major problem with my application. I am new at RoR and got a task from my instructor.

In the task, there's a file like this in view:

```
views:
  account (file)
    edit.html.erb
    tips (file)
      index.html.erb
```

I need to reach action for account->tips->index.html.erb. I wanted to get all the tips that logged in user added to the application. For that part, I am using this code:

```
user = User.find(session[:user_id])
@tips = user.tips
```

When I rendered that page I am getting this output: `Processing by Account::TipsController#index as HTML.`

But I don't know how to write that index action or where to write.

I have tried to write directly in AccountController as index action, it's not working. And also tried to write in TipsController, it's not working as well.

PS: I have another file called 'tips' and it also has an index action.

PS: I cannot change the file order.

Thanks in advance,

Have a safe day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer and would like to share:

In controller,
there is automatically created account file which contains tips_controller in it.
Inside of the TipsController under Account is like this:

```
module Account
  class TipsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @tips = current_user.tips
    end
  end
end
```

Somehow I didn't see this controller for hours!

Have a safe and nice day!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add tips folder to the account views folder. Keep it separate. Moreover, you need to show the TipsController. If it is separate, then the hierarchy should be as follows.
-> app/views/tips/index.html.erb

Comment: Is this a usable solution? It seems like this should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I wrote, I cannot change the folders.